# How do I run external setup program in my Visual Studio setup project

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, installation

I'm using a Visual Studio Setup Project to create a setup program for my new Windows program (single EXE file).  The only thing it seems to be missing is a way to run a component installer.  I need to bundle and run a separate installer EXE with my program, but whenever I try to run it as a custom action, I get the "nested installer" error (You cannot run a setup within a setup).

So, short of buying a commercial installation program ($$$$), is there a way to write a custom action to do this? I've seen a few tutorials on this, and it doesn't look that intimidating, but I'm worried about getting the custom action to run after (or before) that setup transaction lock is freed so the next installer can run.

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: But why can't you just use free installer creators to create standalone installer that lets you install whatever you might need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically what you want, in MSI terms, is a Custom Bootstraper.  Setup and Deployment projects have limited support for this.  [Adding Custom Prerequisites](https://web.archive.org/web/20160626050636/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms165429(v=VS.80).aspx) ([latest version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429%28v=vs.140%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) details how to add pre-requisites to the built-in bootstrapper.

Unfortunately Setup and Deployment projects are not supported in Visual Studio 2012; so, spending much time on something like this may not add much long term value.

WiX is another MSI installer framework that is recommended by folks at Microsoft (the authors work at Microsoft).  It has a feature that it calls [Bundling](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm) that allows chaining of MSIs (via its bootstrapper).  It's really easy to create a WiX project from and existing MSI using a utility called Dark (http://weblogs.asp.net/lorenh/archive/2004/05/09/128899.aspx is a good intro to using Dark).  Once you get that can edit the wxs file to add a bundle.

Other Wix resources: http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial

Comment: WiX is definitely the way to go. Custom Actions are tricky though (in my opinion) which means (as with any other coding activity) lots of reading is required. Good luck!

Comment: AWWWWW YYEEAAAA.  WiX and Burn are exactly what I was looking for. Mad pimpin'!

Comment: Your link to 'Adding Custom Prerequisites' has died in true MS fashion.. in MS words that means 'in the name of a better user experience'.

Comment: @dave Yuck; I added a link to the webarchive version, as well as a link to the latest docs (that the original link should have redirected to :( )

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the free setup/installer creator out there. They will allow you to run any custom scripts during installation, or install any additional components or software.

Here's just to name a few free options:

- [Install Creator](http://www.clickteam.com/website/world/install-creator)
- [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page)
- [Ghost Installer Free](http://www.ethalone.com/free-features.html)
- [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)
- [InstallForge](http://installforge.net/)

Comment: I think what MarcWin detailed was that these "custom scripts" fail with nested installer errors...

Comment: @PeterRitchie you can do exactly that with custom installer creators.